# angular lazy loading not working with webpack production mode

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, bundler

I was trying to bundle all dist folder of angular to single bundle.js file using webpack configuration. I succesfully bundle into single bundle.js file and i am running this bundle.js file inside another project it is working fine until i haven't included lazyloaded module in angular when i include lazyloading module that time it's throwing following error.

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
```

Thanks

Comment: could you show the routing code snippet

Comment: const routes: Routes = [{
  path:'test', loadChildren:'./test/test.module#TestModule'
}];